# Pick contact Intent triggers immediately

Tags: android

Weird problem with Android contact picking.

Running following code in `Fragment`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

This triggers `onActivityResult` immediately when contacts list is opened with `resultCode RESULT_CANCELED`

Any ideas why this is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by changing my `Activity` launchMode to `singleTop` instead of `singleTask`.